# Can you create child-layouts in October CMS?

Tags: octobercms

I want to have a main-layout and then several child-layouts that have some specific styling. Is this possible in October CMS? I cannot find anything on their documentation page.

Comment: Are you able to be more specific?

Comment: Well, I simply mean the ability to have a layout that extends a parent layout. So I might have a layout containing the basic head and script-tags, the container, etc. and then different child-layouts that have different setup, like 3-columns, 1-column, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try using partial, where you define your child-layout code. Here is example for sidebar

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          {% page %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
          <!--right sidebar content-->

            {% partial 'sidebar' %}

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

you can even use some ifs

```
    {% if this.page.id == 'home'  %}
        {% partial 'home-slider' %}
    {% endif %}
```